# How can I search a multi-value field for values exclusively

Tags: solr

I have a Solr index with a multi-valued field, let's call it `mvfield`. It can contain arbitrary values, even though currently it is a finite set of values.

I want to find documents which contain **only** certain values in this field. Example:

- doc1: `mvfield` = [`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`]
- doc2: `mvfield` = [`e`,`f`]
- doc3: `mvfield` = [`f`]
- doc4: `mvfield` = [`a`,`b`,`c`,`e`,`f`]
- doc5: `mvfield` = [`e`]

I want to create a query which returns documents which contain only `e` or `f` in `mvfield`, so in this example it should give *doc2*, *doc3* and *doc5*.

I found a crude workaround using ranges:

- `-mvfield:[* to e} AND -mvfield:{e TO f} AND -mvfield:{f TO *]`

but it seems very fragile. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a filter query.

`&fq=myfield:e` and so on.